# how to integrate a whole click cli module with setuptools entry_points

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, entry-point

Under `spartans/bin/` I have a `click` cli module named `spartans.py` that looks like this:

```
import click

@click.group()
def main():
    ...

@main.command()
def hub_push():
    ...

@main.command()
@click.argument('username', type=str, required=False)
@click.argument('password', type=str, required=False)
def hub_clean(username='', password=''):
    ...

@main.command()
@click.argument('force', type=bool, required=False)
def hub_delete(force=False):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':  # necessary?
    main()
```

I am trying to install the this `spartans` package using setuptools, so that I can run from the command line these commands:

```
$ spartans hub_push
$ spartans hub_clean --username ...
$ spartans hub_delete --force
```

Technically I'm testing on windows, but it should be able to run like that on anything. However, I can't figure out how to get this pattern using setuptools.

If I simply change directory to the folder holding `spartans.py`, the click module lets me use it like this:

```
$ spartans.py hub_push
$ spartans.py hub_clean --username ...
$ spartans.py hub_delete --force
```

but if I want to use `entry_points` with setuptools I have to do it like this:

```
...
entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        "spartans = spartans.bin.spartans:hub_clean",
        # "spartans = spartans.bin.spartans",  # module not callable!
    ]
},
```

Since the module itself isn't callable I don't know how to create the pattern I want above. it seems I'll have to settle for something like:

```
$ spartans-hub_push
$ spartans-hub_clean --username ...
$ spartans-hub_delete --force
```

Where I concatenate the specific command to the module. But this cannot be right. I looked at the documentation but it still only calls a specific function: http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/setuptools/

How do I get `setuptools` to call a `click` cli package?

Comment: I think it should be `"spartans = spartans.bin.spartans:main"`, i.e. the click.group

Comment: @buran that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `"spartans = spartans.bin.spartans:main"`, i.e. use the `click.group`